# How to determine the date a package was installed or updated?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rpm, dpkg

Is there a way to determine the date a package was installed or updated?  What's the proper syntax for both rpm and dpkg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red Hat based distro:

```
$ rpm -q --last <pkg>
$ rpm -qi <pkg>
```

Debian based distro:

```
$ ls -lt /var/lib/dpkg/info/<pkg>.list
```